# Neo4j Isochrones improvement

Tags: neo4j, spatial

i am currently working with isochrones on Neo4j and PostGIS.

My problem in neo4j is that my query for calculating isochrones is not really efficient.

```
match (n:node) where n.id_gis='155'
with n
match path=(n)-[*0..15]-(e)
with e, min(reduce(cost=0.0, r IN rels(path) | cost + toFloat(r.cost2)*3600)) as cost
where cost < 30
return cost, collect(e) as isochrones
order by cost
```

As you can see in the code above i have currently a limit for maximum hops because otherwise it will search for all possible paths in my database before calculating the max cost.

Does anyone have an idea how i can change/improve my query so that it will be executed in a "normal" time and without limiting the amount of relationships?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't do better using Cypher.

You can however do much better using the [traversal framework](http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/3.0/#tutorial-traversal) in Java. See this 2-part blog post comparing the Cypher implementation of Dijkstra's algorithm (similar problem, just with fixed start and end nodes instead of open ended) with [APOC's](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_graph_algorithms_work_in_progress): [part 1](http://blog.bruggen.com/2016/08/orienteering-with-neo4j-moving-from.html) and [part 2](http://blog.bruggen.com/2016/08/orienteering-with-neo4j-solving-1000.html).

Using a traversal, you can compute the cost **while traversing**, which allows you to:

- prune the branch as soon as the maximum cost is reached
- collect the best cost so far for an end node, and prune the branch if the cost of the current branch is worse than the best cost for the same end node

You can use a `Map<Node, Double>` to collect the costs, though if your graph is large enough, using a primitive map (such as [fastutil](http://fastutil.di.unimi.it/), [Trove](http://trove.starlight-systems.com/), [HPPC](http://labs.carrotsearch.com/hppc.html), [Koloboke](https://koloboke.com/), etc.) will use far less memory and be generally faster (more compact, less boxing and unboxing; just use the node's `long` id as the key).

Once the traversal has completed, you just have to inverse the map into a multimap of costs and related end nodes to get your result.

It's more complex than executing a Cypher query, but it'll be much, much faster.

Comment: thank you, that seems like a good solution. 

How can I save a Map for every single path??

Comment: Why a map for every path? The map represents the aggregation of both reachable nodes and costs, it's unique by definition.

Comment: I think i got it. Do you know if it there is a way to traverse depending on the "cost" property of the relationships (like dijkstra) instead of depthFirst?
I read something about implementing an own CostEvaluator and/or PathExpander but that seems very complicated.

Comment: The traversing order will always be depth-first or breadth-first ([`TraversalDescription.order()`](http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/traversal/TraversalDescription.html#order-org.neo4j.graphdb.traversal.BranchOrderingPolicy-) takes an enum parameter). You can however sort the relationships through which the branch is expanded in a `PathExpander`, though it will consume more memory since you'll need to materialize the `Iterable` into a `Collection`.